# Why my Vue Child Component have already assign prop to $data at first, but still accidentally mutate the Parent $data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Please see this minimum example

### App.vue

```html
<template>
  <EditPerseon :previousPerson="persons[0]" />
</template>

<script>
  import EditPerseon from "./EditPerseon.vue";

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        persons: [
          { name: "Bob", age: 18 },
          { name: "Amy", age: 20 },
        ],
      };
    },
    watch: {
      $data: {
        handler() {
          console.log("My $data have been mutated!");
        },
        deep: true,
      },
    },
    components: {
      EditPerseon,
    },
  };
</script>
```

### EditPerseon.vue

```html
<template>
  <input v-model="currentPerson.name" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      previousPerson: Object,
    },
    data() {
      return {
        currentPerson: this.previousPerson,
      };
    },
  };
</script>
```

Also on CodeSandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/why-my-vue-child-component-have-already-assign-prop-to-data-at-first-but-still-accidentaly-mutate-the-parent-data-fueuw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

`EditPerseon.vue` is my child component, but it still accidentally mutate my parent's $data.

Why is this happening?

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Try to watch `persons` instead of `$data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define an object (or an array) assigning it to another object in javaScript, you end up with two references to the same object. I think you believe that your line:

```
currentPerson: this.previousPerson,
```

is somehow creating a new object `currentPerson` that copies the values from `this.previousPerson`. However, what it's happening is that now you have two different variables that both are linked with the original object: so changes to `currentPerson` will actually modify the parent's `person[0]`.

One thing you can do to mitigate this is to forge a new object in the child component:

```
    data() {
      return {
        currentPerson: {...this.previousPerson},
      };
    },
```

or:

```
    data() {
      return {
        currentPerson: {
          name: this.previousPerson.name
        },
      };
    },
```

The first option will fail if some fields of the object are objects themselves. The second one is safer but more verbose. You may try some packages like [cloneDeep](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep) to safely clone objects.

A good general resource to get more info about the deal with object references and copies: https://javascript.info/object-copy.

Apart from this, I believe watcher handlers always trigger at `created`, so the handler will fire even if no change is detected (but I'm not 100% sure about this atm).

Answer (score 1):

Because objects passes by reference. When you change to current person actually you change the original one in the memory.Because of that vue gives warning for that. You need to copy to prevent this.

```
 data() {
  return {
    currentPerson: {...this.previousPerson},
  };
},
```